# Getting response from HTTP Adapter from Worklight

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am new to worklight. I tried to get the json response from the http adapter,
but I am unable to get it to display on device.
I added some alerts in my javascript code and found that it is returning the size of json object as `undefined``.

Here is my adapter javascript file:

```
function getGooglePlaces(location,name) {

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : 'maps/api/place/search/json',
        headers: {
            Host: 'maps.googleapis.com'
        },
        parameters : {
            'key'       :   MyKey,
            'location'  :  location,
            'radius'    :   '10000',
            'sensor'    :   'false',
            'name'      :  name 
        }
    };

    var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

    return response;

}

function addGooglePlace(param1) {

    var input = {
        method : 'put',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : 'userInputRequired'
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

My main.js file:

```
function getLocation()
{

    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(loadHTTPRecords);
    }
    else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
}

function loadHTTPRecords(position){

    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'GooglePlaces',
        procedure : 'getGooglePlaces',
        parameters : [position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude,'dead battery']
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : loadHTTPQuerySuccess,
        onFailure : loadHTTPQueryFailure
    });

}

function loadHTTPQuerySuccess(result){

    WL.Logger.debug("Retrieve success" +  JSON.stringify(result));
    displayFeeds(result);

}

function loadHTTPQueryFailure(result){

    WL.Logger.error("Retrieve failure");
}

function displayFeeds(items){
    alert("In displayFeeds");

    // Get the size of an object

    var ul = $('#itemsList');
    alert("before for loop");

    alert(items.size);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.size; i++) {
        alert("inside for loop 1");
        for(var j=0;j<i;j++){
            alert("in for loop 2");
            var li = $('<li/>').html(items[i].name);

            li.append($('<hr>'));
            ul.append(li);
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

my sample json response

```
{
 "html_attributions": [
 ],
  "isSuccessful": true,
  "responseHeaders": {
   "Alternate-Protocol": "443:quic",
   "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=300",
   "Content-Type": "application\/json; charset=UTF-8",
   "Date": "Tue, 11 Feb 2014 12:04:13 GMT",
   "Expires": "Tue, 11 Feb 2014 12:09:13 GMT",
   "Server": "mafe",
   "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
   "Vary": "Accept-Language",
   "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block"
 },
   "responseTime": 236,
  "results": [
      {
       "geometry": {
        "location": {
           "lat": 52.057049,
           "lng": 1.153298
        }
     },
     "icon": "http:\/\/maps.gstatic.com\/mapfiles\/place_api\/icons\/cafe-71.png",
     "id": "ec0955fb06fd95d639c89d12475624627250abac",
     "name": "Costa Coffee",
     "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": true
     },
     "price_level": 2,
     "rating": 3.9,
     "reference": "CnRuAAAABmdY6kIxRQZw68hqjZ_wwBE29sdSgYuOkXf2IvZTe77aG-AgoCaahu1c9cddHA0Z1D2EdELAEuDyl38xV1G5YcvP3pOm2p0IwVkuvYIJSA1IKAGLIQym21SpXvhUSqBxrpHKBvgTNnUg69lHROaMyxIQvvP8SeCG_dzKi_JgrdrgRRoUQXqH4UkDtA-58bCbdRzUCdXTRVU",
     "types": [
        "cafe",
        "food",
        "establishment"
     ],
     "vicinity": "1-5 Queen St, Ipswich"
  },
```

Comment: do you get the response while invoking the adapter procedure using **Invoke Worklight Procedure**

Comment: Yes i got response when i invoke procedure but the problem is when i try to access an array results,it says 'undefined'

Comment: can you provide the sample result in your question because i think you  are traversing the json in a wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you question properly, through items.size you are trying to get the length of results. If you want to get the length of results you should use `items.invocationResult.results.length` which will give you the total number of results, where items is the response coming from the adapter and `invocationResult` contains the results and other paramaters, from which you will have to access the results for accessing only the particular output.

If i didn't understand your question properly, please tell me exactly what you are trying to get through items.size

Comment: i have a question ,should i use JSON.stringify to convert json object into string and then use items.invocationResult.results

Comment: Yes you can use. Both will give you the same result, but if you want to access the result length, you can directly use item.invocationResult.results.

Comment: Thanks sasi,i got it and one more doubt.in the same response i want to access price_level of each result,but when i run it it says undefined

Comment: If you notice your response, the results is in array format, so if you want to access the price_level, you have mention in which array index you are accessing, for example for this output, you can access like, items.invocationResult.results[0].price_level

Comment: i tried that and writen a console.log to see what it prints,i got 'undefiened' for price_level