# IBM Worklight Mobile invokation of SQL adapter not displaying records

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter, procedure

Following the ibm doc and other blogs, I tried to invoke an SQL adapter to display results in a mobile simulator.

Followed the document "Module_06_-_Invoking_Adapter_Procedures_from_the_Client_Applications.pdf".

Following are my code:-
Step 1
**MOBISQLAdap1-impl.js**

```
var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from sqldb.dbo.table1");
function procedure1(param) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
        parameters : [param]
    });
}
```

While invoking the SQL Adapter, it is displaying the results. All good here!!

Step 2: - Created an **app named Mobi**

Step 3:- **common/js/initOptions.js**
In the common/js/initOptions.js file; uncommented the line and the value is true.

```
var wlInitOptions = {
// # Should application automatically attempt to connect to Worklight Server on application start up
// # The default value is true, we are overriding it to false here.
    connectOnStartup : true,
```

step 4: **common/js/main.js file**

```
function loadSQLRecords(){
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'MOBISQLAdap1',
        procedure : 'procedure1',
        parameters : []
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : loadSQLQuerySuccess,
        onFailure : loadSQLQueryFailure
    });
}

function loadSQLQuerySuccess(result){
    WL.Logger.debug("Retrieve success" +  JSON.stringify(result));
    displayFeeds(result.invocationResult.resultSet);
}

function loadSQLQueryFailure(result){
    WL.Logger.error("Retrieve failure");
}
```

Step 5: **common/js/index.html file; in the body section**

```
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
              <div id="itemsList"></div>
    <!--application UI goes here-->
    Display of data
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
```

The SQL adapter values are not displayed in the app while previewing. Did the build and deploy before previewing.

Any help appreciated. Thanks rb

Comment: While previewing the app, open the Chrome dev tools and look in the Console - what do you see there? Any errors? In addition, you've listed all code -- except for displayFeeds(), that actually displays the feed! Add this code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've omitted from the question the most important code snippet - `displayFeeds()`, making this not possible to debug!

In addtion, you do not mention if there are any errors - open the Chrome dev tools > console and see if there are any errors while previewing the app.

Finally, this has been asked many times. Please search.
Here are a few questions dealing with the same question.

- [IBM Worklight - How to parse adapter response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955837/ibm-worklight-how-to-parse-adapter-response)
- [IBM Worklight - Unable to display data retrieved using SQL adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670179/ibm-worklight-unable-to-display-data-retrieved-using-sql-adapter)
- [Worklight and jquery: I want fetch links present in the xml and want tag them with the row dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303422/worklight-and-jquery-i-want-fetch-links-present-in-the-xml-and-want-tag-them-wi)
- [Getting response from HTTP Adapter from Worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677311/getting-response-from-http-adapter-from-worklight)
- [use resultset returned by WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement within sql adapter procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744628/use-resultset-returned-by-wl-server-invokesqlstatement-within-sql-adapter-proced)

Comment: Thanks Idan. Atlast figured the issue with displaying the JSON in HTML which was in the dislayfeed. Thanks a lot for your instant response.